# How to access the menu item within a frame using Selenium Webdriver or Cypress?

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, cypress, frames

I am having some trouble clicking a menu button on a webpage for work. The error occurs whether I am using Selenium or Cypress. While using cypress I get an uncaught exception error, and an error stating the (html) document cannot be read - while using selenium the element cannot be found.

After I login to the application I can't access anything.

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("frameset")).findElements(By.tagName("frame")).get(1));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > table.section > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1)")).click();
```

I have tried to find it using the xpath as well. I'll also provide a snip of the html. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

[image: HTML Example]

Answer (score 0):

To click on the `<td>` element you need to `switchTo()` the [iframe](/questions/tagged/iframe) ignoring the [iframeset](/questions/tagged/iframeset) using either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("frame#1[src^='displayMenu']")));
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table.menubutton > tr > td")).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//frame[@id='1' and starts-with(@src, 'displayMenu')]")));
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("table[@class='menubutton']//tr/td")).click();
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I have tried the above & it still didn't work.